# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error message, which I am not really sure how to handle. Technically, what I want to do is to upload an image into the database and then display it.

Each time I try to upload an image, this appears. The image has successfully been uploaded to the database, but it is giving me this error instead of rendering the image on the screen.

I have defined setPosts like this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

[image]

I'm guessing the problem is related to the database since on Firebase it looks like this, which I'm certain it's not supposed to.

[image]

Here is the code for UploadImage.js:

```
const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image); 
    uploadTask.on(
        () => {
          storage
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
                db.collection("posts").add({
                    timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
                    caption: caption,
                    imageUrl: url, 
                    username: username
                });

                setCaption("");
                setImage(null);
            });
        }
    );
};
```

I'm kinda new to ReactJS and Firebase. Any help would be appreciated!

*UPDATE* : this is how i render "Post" in App.js

```
{
        posts.map(({id, post}) => (
            <Post key={id} postId={id} user={user} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>
        ))
 }
```

Comment: how are you rendering `posts`?

Comment: We should see you render function in order to understand what the problem is. You're probably just trying to render ```posts``` without using a map function, but we can't be sure without seeing the render function

Comment: If username is an object from Firebase, then you have to pass it down that way. So in your map, where you have ```username={post.username}``` it should be ```username={post.username.username}```. Or in your Post component you will need to use the username prop as ```username.username```. If you don't want to access username this way, then you'll need to figure out why it's getting saved to Firebase as an object rather than a string. Where is "username" coming from, when you store it in Firebase?

Comment: I've updated the question and inserted the code for rendering posts. If i change [username={post.username}]  to [username={post.username.username}] the users disappears from the webpage :( maybe i'm missing something else, not too sure

Comment: What do you mean by "Where is "username" coming from, when you store it in Firebase? " not sue i understand what you mean here

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with this same code-along.  Your question helped me figure out the answer.

Go to your firebase console and check each document (the "posts").  You probably have some from earlier in the code-along. Check the 'username' for each document.  If any of them are an object (they have a down arrow that expands to show another 'username' that is type (string)), delete those.  After doing that, it left me with my most recent upload attempt (you might have to drop all of your earlier 'posts') - but then it worked.